# how to distinguish between value set by user interaction vs binding on a Spark input component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex-spark

How do I determine whether a value set comes from user interaction with the input component, or from binding?

Example:

```
<s:NumericStepper xmlns=...
                  value="{SomeDataManager.foo}">
<fx:Script>
    override public function set value(newValue:Number):void {
        if (setByUser) {
            super.value = newValue;
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
</fx:Script>
</s:NumericStepper>
```

Using Flex 4.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen for the `change` event. It will solve your problem.

```
<s:HGroup>
        <s:NumericStepper change="trace('ns change')" value="{ns2.value}" minimum="{ns2.minimum}" maximum="{ns2.maximum}"/>
        <s:NumericStepper minimum="0" maximum="1000" id="ns2" />
    </s:HGroup>
```

The `change` event gets fired when an input component's value is changed by user interaction. If some part of your code is changing that component's value, the  `change` event will not get fired.

Comment: is it the `Event.CHANGE` event that I need? And how do I get the new value?

Comment: use `NumericStepper(event.currentTarget).value` to get the new value entered.

Comment: CHANGE is a change in value due to user interaction.
VALUE_COMMIT is fired from programmatic changes.

Comment: BTW, did you know that specifically for `NumericStepper`, this is actullay not a good solution because that class is buggy? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-17361